# Конвертация изображения в 256-цветное, Python

Tags: python, изображения, pil, pillow

Необходимо значительно сократить вес изображения (в десятки раз). На входе идёт черно-белое изображение в формате .jpeg. Если я правильно понимаю, оно может хранить в себе 256^3 цветов. Но мне необходимы только все серые оттенки. Не знаю, возможно ли это в принципе. Попробовал сохранять в .gif, но начинает весить ещё больше, как в принципе и с любым другим форматом.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.jpeg').convert('LA')
img.save('1.gif')
```

Comment: Сильно сократить размер - ну, смотря что за изображение. Есть ли там большие одинаковые области и т.д. Навскидку - перепаковать в jpeg с меньшим качеством и/или разрешением. Библиотеки для этого не подскажу. Ну, это помимо перевода в ч/б формат.

Comment: Если картинка именно черно-белая, convert('1')  при условии dither=None при сохранении в gif даст минимальный размер файла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- convert('LA') — конвертит с альфа-каналом.
- convert('L') — конвертит в 8-битовые пиксели ч/б, это похоже на вашу задачу.

Список модов тут: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes